# Code-igniter site moved to localhost to live

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

i have created website using codeigniter and it is working fine in my localhost. CI project path is **http://www.xxxxxxx.com/themes/NPOS**.  i have done following modifications on below files. database connection is ok.

***.htaccess file***

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /themes/NPOS/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

***config.php***

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.xxxxxxx.com/themes/NPOS/';
```

*** ******server has mod_rewrite enable.********* ***

after i have tried to access my site and it gives **404 Not found** error

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /themes/NPOS/login was not found on this server.

what is the reason, any suggestions please.

Comment: try `themes/NPOS/` instead of `/themes/NPOS/`

Comment: @Umair tried, but not working

Comment: missing `RewriteEngine On` in your `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

In config.php, do this changes

> path: `config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['encryption_key'] = '123';
```

then in database.php

> path: `config/database.php`

if CI 2.0

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';//if cPanel this will be loacalhost
$db['default']['username'] = '';//username which create by server
$db['default']['password'] = '';//password
$db['default']['database'] = '';//database name
```

if CI 3.0

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => '',//username which create by server
    'password' => '',//password
    'database' => '',//database name
```

> If **CPanel** Hosting you can open through **Database Wizard**

then **.htaccess** file will be(this should be *place outside of application folder*)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```